# Generic Mapping Method fails to convert to concrete types

Tags: c#, generics, .net-4.5

I am trying to create a generic mapping function that will take in various types that all inherit from NSReportBase and then new up the appropriate object and return it.  So far, I have the following:

```
internal static T BuildNamingStandardType<T>(DataRow dr) where T : NSReportBase, new()
{
    T newNamingStandardReport = null;

    if (typeof(T) is NSPipelineSystems)
        newNamingStandardReport = new NSPipelineSystems(dr["Column1"], dr["Column2"]);
    else if (typeof(T) is NSPipelineSegmentGroups)
        newNamingStandardReport = new NSPipelineSegmentGroups(dr["Column3"]);

    return newNamingStandardReport; 
}
```

However, I am getting an error that each concrete type cannot be implicitly converted to type 'T'.  Given that T is known by the compiler to be of type 'NSReportBase', I am not sure I understand the issue here, let alone how to fix it.

**EDIT**:  I may have over simplified the example.  The challenge is that the constructors do not actually take no arguments, but different numbers and types of columns from the DataRow that is a parameter to the method.  I know that I could do this polymorphically, but I would like to avoid exposing the DataRow column names to my business logic by moving this method into the respective domain objects.

Comment: Did you understand my answer? Or even considered it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Given that T is known by the compiler to be of type 'NSReportBase'

It is not known to the compiler. The C# language does not define that the compiler must derive types through data-flow tracing (in fact it is forbidden to compile this). Humans can see this fact, the language is defined not to see it (but tools like Resharper *can* see it as a utility).

Solution: First cast to `object`, then to the concrete type. This method still feels like a hack to me. Maybe you should evaluate whether you should use generics in the first place. The purpose of generics is that your generic method *does not need to care* about the concrete type.

Answer (score 2):

As long as the type your trying to instantiate has a default constructor you could use the new constraint.

```
where T : new()
```

then you are able to

```
var instance = new T();
```

Also the error comes from the fact that the Compiler only knows that T is of Type `NSReportBase` but when using T becomes either `NSPipelineSystems` or `NSPipelineSegmentGroups` and you cannot assign `NSPipelineSystems` to `NSPipelineSegmentGroups` or vice versa, this is why you get that error.

If you want to solve that you have to change

```
T newNamingStandardReport = null;
```

to

```
NSReportBase newNamingStandardReport = null;
```

and cast the return value manually to (T).

Answer (score 0):

```
internal static T BuildNamingStandardType<T>(DataRow dr) where T : NSReportBase, new()
{
    return new T(); 
}
```

But it isn't clear, why there's a `dr` parameter.